# How to propagate the effect of model bias via MEAS update correctly to other variables in GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

EDIT:  I am just checking if the issue not on the condensate side.

I have a material balance optimisation problem that I have configured in GEKKO. I have reproduced my challenge on a smaller problem that I can share here.

It pertains to the initial values for `CV's` that I have left undefined (defaulting to zero) during controller instantiation and then assigned via the `MEAS` attribute with `FSTATUS=1` parameter before the first call to the `solve()` method.

As expected the controller establishes a `BIAS` to account for the difference between MEAS and the initial controller state.  It then correctly drives optimisation of the biased `CV` to the appropriate target.  However, it then appears to continue to use the unbiased model values for the remaining to calculate other `Intermediate` streams and to use in `Equations`. The result is that the rest of the material balance shifts to a point that is not representing the actual plant operating point.

Attached is a code snippet illustrating my challenge.
The output is:

```
PowerProduced.value [0.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0, 167.0]
PowerProduced.PRED [188.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0, 355.0]
Steam for Generation [1300.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0, 668.0]
```

The `PRED` values are realistic but the values for *Steam for Generation* reverts back to a
explicit positional form rather than an incremental adjustment from the initial condition. I expected  `[1300, 1968, 1968, 1968 ...]`  for *Steam for Generation*

How do I adjust the model configuration to account for this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Nov 30 11:53:50 2022

@author: Jacques Strydom
"""

from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np


m=GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time=np.linspace(0,9,10)

#GLOBAL OPTIONS
m.options.IMODE=6  #control mode,dynamic control, simultaneous
m.options.NODES=2  #collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER=1 # 1=APOPT, 2=BPOPT, 3=IPOPT
m.options.CV_TYPE=1  #2 = squared error from reference trajectory
m.options.CTRL_UNITS=3   #control time steps units (3= HOURS)
m.options.MV_DCOST_SLOPE=2
m.options.CTRL_TIME=1    #1=1 hour per time step
m.options.REQCTRLMODE=3  #3= CONTRO


m.StmToPowerRatio=m.Const(4.0)     #Constant that relates Stm to Power
m.StmToProductRatio=m.Const(1.5)   #Constant that relates Stm to Product

m.SodiumSoftner_Conductivity=m.Param(value=285,name='SodiumSoftner_Conductivity')
m.Condensate_Conductivity   = m.Param(value=10,name='Condensate_Conductivity')
m.Cycles_of_Concentration  = m.Param(value=12,name='COC')
        

m.SodiumSoftner_Production = m.MV(lb=0,ub=2450,name='SodiumSoftner_Production')  #MV
m.Final_Product            = m.MV(lb=0,ub=1400,name='Final Product')  #MV
m.Steam_Produced           = m.MV(lb=0,ub=4320,name='SteamProduced')  #MV
m.OtherNetSteamUsers       = m.MV(name='OtherNetSteamUsers')  #Disturbance Var

m.BFW_Conductivity         =m.CV(name='BFW_Conducitivy')
m.PowerProduced            =m.CV(name='PowerProduced')       

m.Blowdown=m.Intermediate(m.Steam_Produced/(m.Cycles_of_Concentration-1),name='Blowdown')
m.BoilerFeedWater_Required=m.Intermediate(m.Steam_Produced+m.Blowdown,name='BFWRequired')
m.SteamforGeneration=m.Intermediate(m.Steam_Produced-m.StmToProductRatio*m.Final_Product-m.OtherNetSteamUsers,name='StmforPower')
m.CondensateForBFW = m.Intermediate(m.BoilerFeedWater_Required-m.SodiumSoftner_Production,name='Condensate for BFW')
m.Cond_SS_Ratio = m.Intermediate(m.CondensateForBFW/m.BoilerFeedWater_Required)

m.Equation(m.PowerProduced==m.SteamforGeneration/m.StmToPowerRatio)
m.Equation(m.BFW_Conductivity==(m.SodiumSoftner_Production*m.SodiumSoftner_Conductivity+m.CondensateForBFW*m.Condensate_Conductivity)/m.BoilerFeedWater_Required)

#MV SETTINGS

m.SodiumSoftner_Production.STATUS=1     # Manipulate this
m.SodiumSoftner_Production.FSTATUS=1    # MEASURE this
m.SodiumSoftner_Production.COST=-1      # Higher is better

m.Final_Product.STATUS=1                # Manipulate this
m.Final_Product.FSTATUS=1               # Measure this
m.Final_Product.COST=-20                # Higher is better

m.Steam_Produced.STATUS=1               # Manipulate this
m.Steam_Produced.FSTATUS=1              # MEASURE this

m.OtherNetSteamUsers.STATUS=0           # Solver cannot manipulate, disturbance
m.OtherNetSteamUsers.FSTATUS=1          # MEASURE this

m.BFW_Conductivity.STATUS=1             #Control this CV
m.BFW_Conductivity.FSTATUS=1            #MEASURE this CV
m.BFW_Conductivity.WSPHI=50             #Penalty for SPHI violation
m.BFW_Conductivity.WSPLO=50             #Penalty for SPLO violation
m.BFW_Conductivity.SPHI=140             #High limit for target range
m.BFW_Conductivity.SPLO=110             #Low limit for target range

m.PowerProduced.STATUS=1                #Control this CV
m.PowerProduced.FSTATUS=1               #MEASURE this
m.PowerProduced.COST=-2                 #Higher is better
m.PowerProduced.WSPHI=50                #Penalty for SPHI violation
m.PowerProduced.WSPLO=50                #Penalty for SPLO violation
m.PowerProduced.SPHI=355                #High limit for target range
m.PowerProduced.SPLO=100                #Low limit for target range


#Load measurements - realistic mass balance
m.Final_Product.MEAS            =1200
m.SodiumSoftner_Production.MEAS =2200
m.OtherNetSteamUsers.MEAS       =800
m.Steam_Produced.MEAS           =3900
m.BFW_Conductivity.MEAS         =152
m.PowerProduced.MEAS            =188

m.solve()  #solve for first step

print('PowerProduced.value',m.PowerProduced.value)
print('PowerProduced.PRED',m.PowerProduced.PRED)
print('Steam for Generation',m.SteamforGeneration.value)
```

The process associated with the reduced problem is depicted here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gekko uses the unbiased model values to solve the equations. The [BIAS](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionBias) is only applied to that specific CV as an output correction. A state estimation algorithm such as a Kalman filter or Moving Horizon Estimator (MHE) is required to adjust parameters or initial conditions to correct for the difference between measured and model outputs. The bias method is commonly applied to model predictive control as a quick correction when a more complete state estimator is not available. See [preprint](https://apm.byu.edu/prism/uploads/Members/eaton_hedengren_OPTE_springer.pdf) or [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11081-015-9295-9) on various estimation methods, including the bias method.

> Hedengren, J. D., Eaton, A. N., Overview of Estimation Methods for Industrial Dynamic Systems, Optimization and Engineering, Springer, Vol 18 (1), 2017, pp. 155-178, DOI: 10.1007/s11081-015-9295-9.

To include the bias in the model, an external bias calculation is recommended with the creation of `bias1` and `bias2`.

```py
m.bias1                    =m.FV(0); m.bias1.STATUS=0; m.bias1.FSTATUS=1
m.BFW_Conductivity         =m.CV(name='BFW_Conducitivy')

m.bias2                    =m.FV(0); m.bias2.STATUS=0; m.bias2.FSTATUS=1
m.PowerProduced            =m.CV(name='PowerProduced')
```

Substitute the `Var+bias` to use the biased value of the variable. The denominator terms are also rearranged to the other side of the equation to improve the numerical solution potential by avoiding potential divide-by-zero.

```py
m.Equation(m.StmToPowerRatio*(m.PowerProduced+m.bias2)==m.SteamforGeneration)
m.Equation(m.BoilerFeedWater_Required*(m.BFW_Conductivity+m.bias1)==\ 
             (m.SodiumSoftner_Production*m.SodiumSoftner_Conductivity\
               +m.CondensateForBFW*m.Condensate_Conductivity))
```

The equations now use the biased value.

[image: steam generation]

Here is the complete script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m=GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time=np.linspace(0,9,10)

#GLOBAL OPTIONS
m.options.IMODE=6  #control mode,dynamic control, simultaneous
m.options.NODES=2  #collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER=1 # 1=APOPT, 2=BPOPT, 3=IPOPT
m.options.CV_TYPE=1  #2 = squared error from reference trajectory
m.options.CTRL_UNITS=3   #control time steps units (3= HOURS)
m.options.MV_DCOST_SLOPE=2
m.options.CTRL_TIME=1    #1=1 hour per time step
m.options.REQCTRLMODE=3  #3= CONTRO

m.StmToPowerRatio=m.Const(4.0)     #Constant that relates Stm to Power
m.StmToProductRatio=m.Const(1.5)   #Constant that relates Stm to Product

m.SodiumSoftner_Conductivity=m.Param(value=285,name='SodiumSoftner_Conductivity')
m.Condensate_Conductivity   = m.Param(value=10,name='Condensate_Conductivity')
m.Cycles_of_Concentration  = m.Param(value=12,name='COC')
        

m.SodiumSoftner_Production = m.MV(lb=0,ub=2450,name='SodiumSoftner_Production')  #MV
m.Final_Product            = m.MV(lb=0,ub=1400,name='Final Product')  #MV
m.Steam_Produced           = m.MV(lb=0,ub=4320,name='SteamProduced')  #MV
m.OtherNetSteamUsers       = m.MV(name='OtherNetSteamUsers')  #Disturbance Var

m.bias1                    =m.FV(0); m.bias1.STATUS=0; m.bias1.FSTATUS=1
m.BFW_Conductivity         =m.CV(name='BFW_Conducitivy')

m.bias2                    =m.FV(0); m.bias2.STATUS=0; m.bias2.FSTATUS=1
m.PowerProduced            =m.CV(name='PowerProduced')

m.Blowdown=m.Intermediate(m.Steam_Produced/(m.Cycles_of_Concentration-1),name='Blowdown')
m.BoilerFeedWater_Required=m.Intermediate(m.Steam_Produced+m.Blowdown,name='BFWRequired')
m.SteamforGeneration=m.Intermediate(m.Steam_Produced-m.StmToProductRatio*m.Final_Product\
                                    -m.OtherNetSteamUsers,name='StmforPower')
m.CondensateForBFW = m.Intermediate(m.BoilerFeedWater_Required\
                                    -m.SodiumSoftner_Production,name='Condensate for BFW')
m.Cond_SS_Ratio = m.Intermediate(m.CondensateForBFW/m.BoilerFeedWater_Required)

m.Equation(m.StmToPowerRatio*(m.PowerProduced-m.bias2)==m.SteamforGeneration)
m.Equation(m.BoilerFeedWater_Required*(m.BFW_Conductivity-m.bias1)==\
            (m.SodiumSoftner_Production*m.SodiumSoftner_Conductivity\
             +m.CondensateForBFW*m.Condensate_Conductivity))

#MV SETTINGS

m.SodiumSoftner_Production.STATUS=1     # Manipulate this
m.SodiumSoftner_Production.FSTATUS=1    # MEASURE this
m.SodiumSoftner_Production.COST=-1      # Higher is better

m.Final_Product.STATUS=1                # Manipulate this
m.Final_Product.FSTATUS=1               # Measure this
m.Final_Product.COST=-20                # Higher is better

m.Steam_Produced.STATUS=1               # Manipulate this
m.Steam_Produced.FSTATUS=1              # MEASURE this

m.OtherNetSteamUsers.STATUS=0           # Solver cannot manipulate, disturbance
m.OtherNetSteamUsers.FSTATUS=1          # MEASURE this

m.BFW_Conductivity.STATUS=1             #Control this CV
m.BFW_Conductivity.FSTATUS=0            #MEASURE this CV
m.BFW_Conductivity.WSPHI=50             #Penalty for SPHI violation
m.BFW_Conductivity.WSPLO=50             #Penalty for SPLO violation
m.BFW_Conductivity.SPHI=140             #High limit for target range
m.BFW_Conductivity.SPLO=110             #Low limit for target range

m.PowerProduced.STATUS=1                #Control this CV
m.PowerProduced.FSTATUS=0               #MEASURE this
m.PowerProduced.COST=-2                 #Higher is better
m.PowerProduced.WSPHI=50                #Penalty for SPHI violation
m.PowerProduced.WSPLO=50                #Penalty for SPLO violation
m.PowerProduced.SPHI=355                #High limit for target range
m.PowerProduced.SPLO=100                #Low limit for target range

#Load measurements - realistic mass balance
m.Final_Product.MEAS            =1200
m.SodiumSoftner_Production.MEAS =2200
m.OtherNetSteamUsers.MEAS       =800
m.Steam_Produced.MEAS           =3900
#m.BFW_Conductivity.MEAS         =152
m.bias1.MEAS                    =-152
#m.PowerProduced.MEAS            =188
m.bias2.MEAS                    =-188

m.solve()  #solve for first step

print('PowerProduced.value',m.PowerProduced.value)
print('PowerProduced.PRED',m.PowerProduced.PRED)
print('Steam for Generation',m.SteamforGeneration.value)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,m.SteamforGeneration.value,'r-',label='SteamforGeneration')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,m.Steam_Produced.value,'r-.',label='Steam_Produced')
plt.plot(m.time,-1.5*np.array(m.Final_Product.value),'b--',label='Final_Product')
plt.plot(m.time,-np.array(m.OtherNetSteamUsers.value),'k:',label='OtherNetSteamUsers')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```